# How to close HTTP connection when timeout to occur in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I realized that after the timeout the HTTP connection is still trying to connect. I found this out by turning on my server after the timeout happened.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

...

http.Response response = await http.post("$URL/oauth/token",
  headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth},
  body: bodyEncoded,
).timeout(Duration(seconds: 10));
```

How to force close connection?

Comment: Call the close() method?

Comment: I think it doesn't have this method. You can use [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution

```
...
  HttpClient client = HttpClient();
  client.connectionTimeout = Duration(seconds: 10);

  HttpClientRequest request = await client.postUrl(Uri.parse("$URL/a/b/c"));
  request.headers.add('authorization', basicAuth);
  request.headers.add('content-Type', 'application/json');
  request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode( map )));
  HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();

  String responseBody;
  await response.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((contents) => responseBody = contents);
  return http.Response(responseBody, response.statusCode);
```

But, request.close() appears to have a read byte limit.
Is reading a maximum of 1907 bytes.